# Best way to design a maven dependency and avoid abstraction leak in Java?

Tags: java, maven, oop, maven-3

I'm sorry my question seems to be broad. I'd just like to clear up some things. I've read the thread on abstraction leak and some other articles. From what I understand, abstraction leak is when the "user" or developer sees the complicated processes behind a function...? Like in hiding the complicated engineering of a car or the secret that reliable TCP relies on unreliable IP. But I was looking on some classes in Java, particularly the List family. What I observed was the `List interface, AbstractList, ArrayList, and AbstractArrayList.` I noticed some weird stuff in ArrayList class.
First I found this

```
   public E get(int index) {
        rangeCheck(index);
        return elementData(index);
    }
```

Then this

```
    public E get(int index) {
        rangeCheck(index);
        checkForComodification();
        return ArrayList.this.elementData(offset + index);
    }
```

They have the same function name which I take is overloading, however they also take the same parameters? When I use get, how would I know which is used? And *is this legal in OOP?*

Next note, I found this on List:

```
default void sort(Comparator<? super E> c) {
    Object[] a = this.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(a, (Comparator) c);
    ListIterator<E> i = this.listIterator();
    for (Object e : a) {
        i.next();
        i.set((E) e);
    }
}
```

I was wondering why they chose to add defaults to List. I once had an interface that had a default contract but someone pointed out that it was causing an abstraction/memory leak. `When is it considered to be a good practice to use defaults in an interface?`

Lastly, I had made a "custom" List in the dependency I am making.

```
class CustomList<T> extends ArrayList<T>{
//sample function: void sortInTheSmartestMagicalWayIdk();
}
```

This was pointed out to be a **design flaw**, too. "It's dependent on ArrayList. What if ArrayList becomes ***obsolete*** in the future? Then so will be the dependency you are making." This was what I was told. Yes it does sound right, so what would have been the best way to add some custom functions to a List Class? And if I wanted an entity in my project to act as a List, Should I *create an interface that extends List, then create an implementation of that interface and use that implementation as my "Custom List"?*

Comment: Having two functions with the same signature is illegal. Which ArrayList did you see? There is a difference between public interface and a published interface. ArrayList<T> is part of the published interface of JDK and I expect oracle to think multiple times before changing it. It is perfectly OK to use it and extend your class from it. Have a look at this: https://www.martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/published.pdf

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ so I just click on ArrayList and it opens the ArrayList class. The get functions which i showed above were within the ***SAME*** class.

Comment: I'd like to upload a picture of it but pictures here are like raisins to breads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems a bit unfocused.

**1)** On two `get` methods: one belongs to `ArrayList` the other belongs to `private class SubList`. Take a closer look at indentation, you'll see immediately that these two methods aren't even on the same indentation level.

**2)** If it's likely that the method will be implemented in exactly the same way in most of the implementing classes, you *should* provide a default implementation. If the interface is too general, and does not allow to implement a method in reasonably efficient way, it might be better *not to* provide a default implementation, in order to signal to the implementers of the interface that this method is not provided for free, and requires some attention and effort.

**3)** In your `CustomList`, do you want the users of your interface to rely on the guarantee that it will always be a special kind of `ArrayList`? If this is the case (very unlikely), then you can leave it as is. If this is not the case, you should get rid of `extends ArrayList` and replace it by `implements List`, and then maybe wrap an `ArrayList` inside the implementation. If you then later decide that `ArrayList` wasn't the best idea, you can replace the private wrapped member variable by some other implementation, without breaking the code of all the people who use your API.

Comment: Yes I apologize for the unfocused question. My knowledge in OOP still lacks some experience. Thank you for your answer. Ah I feel for not noticing the second get inside SubList. How about this question.***When does an abstraction leak apply?*** I'm still a bit confused. Should it be like how System.out.println hides the write function so deep that the user thinks prinln is simply printing a string?

Comment: It doesn't have to do anything with "deep" or with what the user "thinks". In the case of `System.out`, the user sees that it is a `PrintStream`, which can do much more than just `println`. The problem with `CustomList extends ArrayList` would be that the users of your class could invoke the method `trimToSize()` on it. If you later decided to change the implementation from `ArrayList` to `Set`, you'd either have to keep the nonsensical method `trimToSize()` in your interface, or break user code. Both variants are bad: this is because `trimToSize()` (and all the other innards) have *leaked*.

Comment: Ohhhhh. Okay okay. Thanks for clearing that up.